# Whenever I want to run the flask the below error is showing even none of the browsers are open

Tags: python, flask

I want the solution for below error:

```
(venflask) sgiri@sgiri-Latitude-3580:~/NewEnv$ flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sgiri/NewEnv/venflask/bin/flask", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/sgiri/NewEnv/venflask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 966, in main
    cli.main(prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "/home/sgiri/NewEnv/venflask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sgiri/NewEnv/venflask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/sgiri/NewEnv/venflask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/sgiri/NewEnv/venflask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/sgiri/NewEnv/venflask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sgiri/NewEnv/venflask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sgiri/NewEnv/venflask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sgiri/NewEnv/venflask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 852, in run_command
    run_simple(
  File "/home/sgiri/NewEnv/venflask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1012, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/home/sgiri/NewEnv/venflask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 956, in inner
    srv = make_server(
  File "/home/sgiri/NewEnv/venflask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 807, in make_server
    return ThreadedWSGIServer(
  File "/home/sgiri/NewEnv/venflask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 701, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/server.py", line 137, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the port of the Flask app again. That's why this error occurred. You can stop the project and run it again from your editor.

Also, this also doesn't work for you then you can use the following commands:

```
 lsof -i:<port_number>
 kill -9 <pid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably already use the port that use your Flask app.
Also, use the magic quote to put your errors next time :)